# Labels do not fit into TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add `labels` (right and left side) on the `tableView`. However, `label texts` are cut, I wonder how to solve. I am adding my source code as well as attached the screen-capture.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"$ %@", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"]];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         return 70.0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Create a custom cell and add two labels at the both end.

Comment: set the label.numberOfLines = 0

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in two ways

one you need to change the textalignment to right, for e.g

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

or change your UITableViewCell style as `Right Detail` in attribute inspector in your `XCode`

[image]

ir change your `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` to `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` or `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`

you can get the style property in `UITableViewCell class`

[image]

and call like

```
   if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"Yesterday";
```

for more information you can get the sample [here](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/) else create the Custom cell and set the label in right alignment based on your needs

Comment: I have added but there are some issues, please see attached figure

Comment: I have added an attached figure to my question to show you tableview label does not fit.

Comment: you dont want the tail in your label

Comment: I want both labels to fit into the screen that user could able to see them.

Comment: try with `[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];` and `[cell. detailTextLabel sizeToFit];`

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line of code:

```
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"Yesterday";

    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
- (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"Yesterday";
    cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];//If you want decrease font size here
    cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I checked its working fine for me whats the problem you are getting now

Answer (score 0):

> You can wrap your label by using NSLineBreakByCharWrapping

**Go through this code here myLabelWidth is ur label width and myLabelHeight is your label height**

```
        CGSize size = [textLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:
                   @{NSFontAttributeName:
                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
    int sizeofL=size.width;
    if(sizeofL>(mylabelWidth))
    {
        [textLabel setMinimumFontSize:5.0];
        [textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

        int hgtofL=size.height;
        if(hgtofL>mylabelHieght)
        {
            if(height<1024)
                textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            else
                textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        }
        else
        {
            if(height<1024)
                textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
            else
                textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
        }

        textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        [textLabel sizeToFit];
    }
    else
    {
        if(height<1024)
            textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
        else
            textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    }

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10000, 0, 0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
    [cell setEditing:NO];
}
```